# How to find pandas cell values that are present in every subset defined by the column before?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df` that looks like this (**Input**):

```
Item  Color
Car   1
Car   2
Bike  3
Bike  1
Train 4
Train 1
```

I want to find every `Color` value that commonly occurs at least once for every `Item` value (**Output**):

```
Item Color
Car   1
Bike  1
Train 1
```

My current approach is based on a loop and admittedly ugly. I am sure there is a more pythonic/efficient way, ideally a one-liner.

```
all_colors = df.Color.unique().tolist()
for single_color in all_colors:
    df_slice = df[df.Color = single_color]
    if len(df_slice) = len(df.Item.unique().tolist()):
       print "Shared Color", single_color
       print df_slice
    else:
       continue
```

**How to find pandas cell values that are present in every subset defined by the column before?**

Edit: The question title is also bulky - if someone has better phrasing, feel free

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
Using `groupby` + `value_counts` + `unstack`, followed by a not-null check.

```
v = df.groupby('Item').Color.value_counts().unstack().notnull().all(0)
df[df.Color.isin(v.index[v])]

    Item  Color
0    Car      1
3   Bike      1
5  Train      1
```

*Details*
The result of the `groupby` followed by `unstack` looks like this:

```
df.groupby('Item').Color.value_counts().unstack()

Color    1    2    3    4
Item                     
Bike   1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
Car    1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
Train  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
```

Now, just find the column that does not have any NaNs, using `notnull` + `all` long the rows. Then, use that to index into `df`.

---

**Option 2**
`get_dummies` + `sum` -

```
v = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('Item').Color).sum(0).eq(df.Item.nunique())
df[df.Color.isin(v.index[v])]

    Item  Color
0    Car      1
3   Bike      1
5  Train      1
```

*Details*

Here, I leverage `get_dummies` and find which colors have been represented #`df.Item.nunique()` number of times.

```
pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('Item').Color).sum(0)

1    3
2    1
3    1
4    1
dtype: int64

df.Item.nunique()
3
```

---

**Option 3**
Similar to the first two, but this uses `pd.crosstab`, and you then just check the count is greater than, or equal to `1` for all rows:

```
v = pd.crosstab(df.Item, df.Color).ge(1).all(0)
df[df.Color.isin(v.index[v])]

    Item  Color
0    Car      1
3   Bike      1
5  Train      1
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `duplicated`

```
df[df.duplicated('Color',keep=False)]
Out[1148]: 
    Item  Color
0    Car      1
3   Bike      1
5  Train      1
```

Thank for cold point it out

```
v=(df.groupby('Color').agg(lambda x : len(list(x)))==df.Item.nunique())
v.index[v.Item]
Out[1174]: Int64Index([1], dtype='int64', name='Color')
df.loc[df.Color.isin(v.index[v.Item]),:]
Out[1175]: 
    Item  Color
0    Car      1
3   Bike      1
5  Train      1
```

Comment: on which data would it not work (just for me to understand)?

Comment: @sudonym Yes, because it doesn't take `Item` into account. Add an extra row: `Bike    2` and try this again.

Comment: Np... it's better now, but `idxmax` will only take the first True value. In case there are multiple colors that satisfy this requirement, only one is returned, because of `idxmax`.

Answer (score 1):

Find our the colors whose unique number of items equals 3. Filter out with `isin` as boolean indexing.

```
num_unique = df.groupby("Color")["Item"].nunique().reset_index()
df[df.Color.isin(num_unique[num_unique.Item == 3].Color)]

    Item    Color
0   Car     1
3   Bike    1
5   Train   1
```